# Ford–Fulkerson with irrational numbers

Tags: algorithms, ford-fulkerson

I am trying to understand why Ford–Fulkerson Algorithm for finding maximum flows doesn't work with irrational numbers? I tried to draw several examples but it seems to work.

Comment: There is a well-known example that has also made its way onto the relevant [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm#Non-terminating_example), which you could easily have found.